# How to pass objects to a form and submit them in Django

Tags: django, object, django-forms

I have an application where I allow importing from CSV files. A list of Libraries are contained in the CSV file. I need to first parse them into a list of Library instances, display them on another page, after user clicks "confirm", these libraries are saved.

Here is my Form:

```
class LibCsvForm(forms.Form):
    lib_csv  = forms.FileField(label='CSV file')

class LibListForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_libs = kwargs.pop('new_libs')
        super(LibListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['new_libs'] = new_libs
```

And my views:

```
def import_lib_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LibCsvForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            raw = request.FILES['lib_csv'].read()
            new_libs = []
            # Process string 'raw' and add instances of Library to new_libs
            context = RequestContext(request, {'form': LibListForm(new_libs=new_libs)})
            context.update(csrf(request))
            return render_to_response('master/library.csv.confirm.html', context)
    else:
        form = LibCsvForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, { 'form': form })
    return render_to_response('master/library.csv.html', variables)
```

A LibCsvForm is just for user to upload a file. Method "import_lib_csv" is to read the file, create instances, and pass them to another form LibListForm, which contains only 'new_libs'. After the user clicks 'confirm', I would like to get this list and save the objects.

The problem is that, in the template:

```
{{ form.new_libs }}
{% for lib in new_libs %}
     {{ lib.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

It does not show anything. I think I did not pass the 'new_libs' into the form properly. Could anybody help? Thanks.

---

Edit:

Thanks, Rohan. I modified it as you mention. Now the library list can be displayed on in the template. 'new_libs' is a list of Library instances.

But when I click "confirm", it reports error. Here is my method to save:

```
def save_lib_list(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = LibListForm(request.POST)
        print form.cleaned_data['new_libs']
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'lib_list': Library.objects.all()
    })
    return render_to_response('master/library.list.html', variables)
```

Django says

```
"Exception Type:    KeyError
Exception Value:    'new_libs' "
```

My template is:

```
<form method="post" action="/library/savelist/" class="well">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <legend>Libraries to import</legend>
    {% for lib in new_libs %}
        {{ lib.id }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

I think i miss something here, but not know how to solve...

---

Solved:

Save the content of uploaded CSV file on the server first. Set the path of this file as a hidden field in the LibListForm:

```
tmp_lib_file = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial='tmp.lib')
```

Then when user clicks 'confirm', parse the file again and get instances of Library, save them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `new_libs` in the template context if you want to use it in template.

```
context = RequestContext(request, {'form': LibListForm(new_libs=new_libs), 'new_libs': new_libs})
```

Also, what is the type of `new_libs` that you pass to `LibListForm`? If its not a proper field type if would not be displayed/processed properly.

Update after question edit:

- The error suggests that there is no `new_fields` key in the `form.cleaned_data`. The form should have a field with that name. `new_field` doesn't seem to be a form field.
- Also your template doesn't have form fields?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what `new_libs` is supposed to be, but it doesn't seem to be a form field at all.

Forms, not surprisingly, will only display form fields. I'm not quite sure why you want to put these objects on a form: it sounds like you really just want to list them on the template, and add a "Confirm" button. No need for a form class for that: just pass them to the template as whatever objects they actually are, iterate through them, and put the confirmation button in a basic HTML form.

Comment: @Daniel_Roseman: my Library instance have a lot of attributes. I tried to do as you suggest, but it seems very complicated to get the objects 'new_libs' back, and save them...

Comment: 'new_libs' is a list of Library instances. Shall I add a field 'new_libs' in LibListForm (maybe ModelChoiceField?), and set the default values, set them as hidden on the template?

Comment: Er, what? What does the number of attributes have to do with anything? And why would putting them into a form make it any less complicated to get them back and save them? You'd need to do that whatever happens: there are two requests involved (showing the form, and processing the confirmation) and Django certainly won't keep those objects around between those two.

Comment: So in the template, i should have something like this: <input type=hidden, name='lib_0_name', value='name1'\>, <input type=hidden, name='lib_1_name', value='name2'\>...?

Comment: I was thinking of making a Form with a filed called 'new_libs' with some default value (from csv file), this field maybe a ModelChoiceField. Then in the template, i hide this field, so that when submitting the form, these default values are passed directly. I have some ModelForm with 'queryset' which would make this happen. But do no know whether it can work out for the example above...